# Improve this conversion chain from flat images to 3d mockup with ImageMagick

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, exec, thumbnails

I was wondering about ways to improve or shorten an ImageMagick conversion (I am rather new to ImageMagick myself).

What I have is a flat image (left in 1) and a 3d mock up that has transparent areas (right in 1, the dashed gets filled, blue and grey are solid ontop) that get filled with the transformed flat image.

I played around with several ImageMagick commands, and list them here for each step (no real numbers). What I am looking for is how to shorten/combine this sequence and the number of helper images created to get to the final image:

1. My given input images. (Scroll down to 5. to see how these two should be combined to get my wanted output...)
2. Crop the flash image and skew the two resulting parts (I noticed that the crop command spits you out the cropped result and overflow, so I use that to separate the sides of the flat image):

   ```
   # sequence for left side:
   convert base.png -crop WxH parts.png
   convert parts-0.png -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective /
           '....' (-resize WxH) front-skewed.png

   #[... same for the right side ...]
   ```
3. Combine the skewed parts:

   ```
   convert front-skewed.png side-skewed.png +append fill.png
   ```
4. Combine the skewed fill and the mockup cover/mask, so that the fill gets inserted under the transparent parts of the cover.png (right image):

   ```
   composite fill.png cover.png -compose dst-atop -matte final.png
   ```
5. Result after deleting the unwanted intermediary images.

[image: illustration of my process steps]

I will be running this from PHP via a `exec`, so any hint on how to do this more smoothly is welcome. I suppose I have to call each transformation as a seperate `exec` call, no?

This won't run excessively but only now and then when a new image gets added, so performance is not that much of a concern for me.

Comment: I do not quite understand: does this process chain already work for you? And you are looking for ways to optimize it?

Comment: "I was wondering about ways to improve or shorten an ImageMagick conversion". It does work like this, but I am wondering how to make it better.

Comment: Your general algorithm is Ok and can't be improved much. But if you have working separate commands which you run sequentially, and since for you *'performance is not that much of a concern'*: there's not much else that could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases you can put separate ImageMagick commands which are 'chained' (i.e. where a following command uses as input image the output image from a previous command) into one single command.

Since you do...

- ...neither provide your input images separately (your [good!] illustration has it 'all-in-one'),
- ...nor your exact separate IM commands,...

...I'm not inclined to construct my own example images and example commands to demonstrate and examplify this method.

I'll leave it at just pointing you to these resources:

- [Working with ordered lists of images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#image_list)
- ['Cloning' or 'duplicating' images inside an ordered list of images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#clone)
- [Parenthesis -- processing images 'on the side'](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis)
- [Sequencing image operations](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#seq_combine)
- [Debugging complex operation sequences](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#complex)

Comment: Thanks for the links. From a beginners point of view I just thought the commands I listed could be somehow simplified or maybe even replaced by more effective ones. I suppose using brackets / lists (thanks for the link) I might be able to shorten things a bit. I am not saying I want someone to rewrite my code, but rather have someone knowledgeable about imagemagick look at what I put together from different example and tutorial pages and see if that makes sense :)